# Path's job queue callback from server

Tags: android, networking, jobs, job-queue

Using the [Path JobQueue library](https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue), is there a way to know when data has been successfully sent to the server? For instance if I were using AsyncTask, then onPostExecute would be the callback method.

In the Path JobQueue library, per my understanding, onRun is analogous to AsynTask's doInBackground; and onAdd is for when data is persisted to local disk. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

OnPostExecute handles the data returned from onRun, therefore you can put the code in the onPostExecute method after the long running command.